# ListView with footer attached, smoothScrollToPosition not functioning correctly

Tags: android, listview, smooth-scrolling

I'm working with a rather large layout that includes a ListView and a LinearLayout beneath it as a footer. I first tried to wrap this in a ScrollView to make the whole layout scrollable, but ran into problems due to both the ListView and the ScrollView being incompatible with each other since they both have scrollable features. So, a workaround was to include the LinearLayout as a footer to the ListView.

Now, in the LinearLayout, I have buttons at various places that the user can click to return to the top of the page. The behaviour I am getting from this is odd, to say the least.

If I have not scrolled down too far, the buttons function normally. However, if I scroll down a bit too far, then clicking the button (even the same buttons that previously worked) will result in the layout scrolling up to roughly half of the way up the listview instead of the top.

Here is the method that does the scrolling, it's rather simple:

```
    public void backToTop(View view) {
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
```

This method is triggered when any of the buttons are clicked.

I have also tried to use the "scrollTo(0, 0)" function, but that failed to do anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

**edit: After testing some more, it appears as though the point where scrolling does not seem to function properly anymore is when the listview is no longer visible on the page. As soon as I scroll past it, the buttons begin to function incorrectly.

Edit 2: SOLVED. My solution: I changed the line

```
    lv.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

to:

```
    lv.setSelected(0);
```

This seems to give the correct behaviour for all my buttons at any position that the user has placed their screen. Using setSelected does not seem to have the side-effect that I was expecting of automatically triggering the click-event. Hooray!

Comment: how do you manage to scroll the entire list out of screen. I mean it stops at the bottom of the page right. Can you post snapshots. Also, just try requestFocus on listView once.

Comment: I mean when the list part of the listview goes off of the screen. If I keep scrolling through the large footer layout I have attached to it, the listview will go off of screen. When I reach the end of the footer I am unable to scroll down any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: I changed the second line of my backToTop method:

```
    lv.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

to:

```
    lv.setSelected(0);
```

This seems to give the correct behaviour for all my buttons at any position that the user has placed their screen. Using setSelected does not seem to have the side-effect that I was expecting of automatically triggering the click-event. Hooray!